# How to use sed to remove variables value from a string

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I am writing a script in bash and I can remove a string from a sentence using the code below:

```
echo 'This is a foo test' | sed 's/\<foo\>//g'
```

> OUTPUT: 'This is a test'

However, I want to be able to replace the foo with a variable. I tried the command below but it does not remove the values from the sentence.

```
temp="foo"
echo 'This is a foo test' | sed 's/\<$temp\>//g'
```

> OUTPUT: 'This is a foo test'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within single quotes the variable is not substituted (because `$` has no special meaning withing single quotes). You can use double quotes instead:

```
echo 'This is a foo test' | sed "s/\<$temp\>//g"
```